# Does String args[] parameter create a new instance of String?

Tags: java

Does the parameter `String args[]` for accepting commandline arguments in `main()` have an impact  if no commandline arguments are provided.

Does it:

1. Create a new object of String?
2. Is any memory allocated to it?

What does Java do when it encounters `String args[]`?

Update:
Wanted to ask a related a Question: If no cmdline args are provided, Will String args[] be empty or null?

Comment: Yes, you will be wasting 16 bytes which is costs about 0.00003 cents of memory ;)

Comment: Well, Piotr Gwiazda says only a String [] is created (not String object), so will it still consume 16 bytes?

Comment: A `String[]` is an object and an empty one will be about 16 bytes.

Comment: That was helpful. How can I calculate that myself?

Comment: The size is JVM dependant. Most of 32-bit JVMs uses 4 bytes for reference and 64-bit uses 8 bytes. But you can run in compressed mode or something... As for empty `String[]` object I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A String[] is an object and an empty one will be about 16 bytes.
>
> That was helpful. How can I calculate that myself?

```
public static long memoryUsed() {
    final Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    return rt.totalMemory() - rt.freeMemory();
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    long before = memoryUsed();
    String[] arr = { };
    long after = memoryUsed();
    if(before == after) throw new AssertionError("you need to turn off the TLAB with -XX:-UseTLAB");
    System.out.printf("The String[] used %,d bytes of memory%n", (after - before));
}
```

prints

```
The String[] used 16 bytes of memory
```

Note: this print how much memory was used to create an object.  This can be more than the amount retained if temporary objects are created.

Comment: How to turn off TLAB? Sorry I feel like a beginner seeing all this

Comment: I get the following output `>javac -XX:-UseTLab TestC.java
javac: invalid flag: -XX:-UseTLab.`    I even tried this option with java command. I also searched a lot on the internet for usage of this option. But I'm not being able to switch off the TLabs. Thanks for the continued interest in my question

Comment: Java is case sensitive. ;) This is a runtime option in any case `javac TestC.java ; java -cp . -XX:-UseTLAB TestC`

Comment: Thanks. it worked: For any who are stuck, this was the command: `java -XX:-UseTLAB TestC`  (after compiling)

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you pass some command-line arguments it creates String objects. `String args[]` is only a reference to the table object. If no arguments are provided `args` would be empty. What is more in `args` you can have only parameters. In C/C++ e.g. you would have also e.g. application name. Java is different. Read more about command-line arguments here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html

Comment: Can you tell me what is the table object?

Comment: Tables are objects in Java. Notice that you can call some methods on them (e.g. `length`) what would be impossible if they would be some primitives as in C.

Answer (score 1):

This code creates one `String[]` reference on the **stack** and one `String[]` object (an empty array) on the **heap**. No `String` objects are created.

Answer (score 0):

If the program is called without command line arguments,  `args[]` is empty, so no `String` is created. You will have an empty array then.